# Map dataframe column value by another column's value

Tags: python, performance, pandas

My dataframe has a month column with values that repeat as `Apr`, `Apr.1`, `Apr.2` etc. because there is no year column. I added a year column based on the month value using a for loop as shown below, but I'd like to find a more efficient way to do this:

```
Products['Year'] = '2015'
for i in range(0, len(Products.Month)):
    if '.1' in Products['Month'][i]:
        Products['Year'][i] = '2016'
    elif '.2' in Products['Month'][i]:
        Products['Year'][i] = '2017'
```

Comment: there is not a more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.str` and treat the whole columns like string to split at the dot.
Now, apply a function that takes the number string and turns into a new year value if possible.

Starting dataframe:

```
   Month
0    Apr
1  Apr.1
2  Apr.2
```

Solution:

```
def get_year(entry):
    value = 2015
    try:
        value += int(entry[-1])
    finally:
        return str(value)

df['Year'] = df.Month.str.split('.').apply(get_year)
```

Now `df` is:

```
   Month  Year
0    Apr  2015
1  Apr.1  2016
2  Apr.2  2017
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` after splitting and add `2015` i.e

```
df['new'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Month'].str.split('.').str[-1],errors='coerce').fillna(0) + 2015

# Sample DataFrame from @ Mike Muller
   Month  Year     new
0    Apr  2015  2015.0
1  Apr.1  2016  2016.0
2  Apr.2  2017  2017.0
```